# Automatic punch hole removal for scanned PDFs

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, automation

Does anyone know of a tool that can automatically bulk remove punch holes from scanned PDFs? It should really do its job mostly autonomously since it will be used on a few hundred pages. It should be compatible with Yosemite (10.10.2).

Comment: Have never had the need to use it, but it might be worthwhile to look at the scan optimization features of Acrobat Pro.

Comment: I looked at Acrobat. It does not seem to have an automated tool for this.